# Ansible remove quote from ansbile fact value

Tags: ansible

I have below task to setup IPv6 not disable settings.  when I used `ansible_default_ipv4.interface` values its including to quote value. how to remove the quote from ansible fact value for below task?

```
- name: Ensure IPv6 not disabled with sysctl
  sysctl:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    value: '0'
    state: present
    sysctl_file: /etc/sysctl.conf
    reload: yes
  with_items:   
    - "net.ipv6.conf.{{ ansible_default_ipv4.interface }}.disable_ipv6"
  ignore_errors: yes
```

This gives below message

```
 cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/\"ens192\"/disable_ipv6: No such file or directory\
```

Here is the fact value:

```
"ansible_default_ipv4": {            
            "alias": "ens192",             
            "interface": "ens192",            
            "mtu": 1500,            
            "type": "ether"
        },
```

Thanks
SR

Comment: Not sure why the error comes, are you on a recent ansible version? By the way, since you are populating the "item" in the `with_items` clause, you dont need to use the curly brackets in the `name` line, i.e you can use: `name: item` but again, your task should work as is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me in Ansible 2.9.6. For example

```yaml
    - sysctl:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        value: "1"
      register: result
      with_items:
        - "net.ipv4.conf.{{ ansible_default_ipv4.interface }}.forwarding"
    - debug:
        var: result
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [sysctl] ****
ok: [localhost] => (item=net.ipv4.conf.eth0.forwarding)

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  result:
    changed: false
    msg: All items completed
    results:
    - ansible_loop_var: item
      changed: false
      failed: false
      invocation:
        module_args:
          ignoreerrors: false
          name: net.ipv4.conf.eth0.forwarding
          reload: true
          state: present
          sysctl_file: /etc/sysctl.conf
          sysctl_set: false
          value: '1'
      item: net.ipv4.conf.eth0.forwarding
```

Comment: same didn't work for me. I am using `ansible 2.9.10` client machine is `CentOS 8`

Comment: IMHO, it's not sysctl problem. I'd test the concatenation, e.g.`"{{ 'begin.' ~ ansible_default_ipv4.interface ~ '.end' }}"`

Comment: first time ran it like this `net.ipv6.conf."{{ ansible_default_ipv4.interface }}".disable_ipv6`. it added this line in `/etc/sysctl.conf` file. after removing this file from file it ran fine. Thanks

Comment: See [When to quote variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#when-to-quote-variables-a-yaml-gotcha).